# How to closed lines? \oval

Tags: diagrams

How to close lines in this? I tried and failed!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(50,50)
\put(22.5,7){\oval(3,2)[lt]}
\put(22.5,7){\oval(3,2)[bl]}
\put(22.5,7){\oval(3,2)[tr]}
\put(25,7){\oval(2,2)[b]}
\put(27.5,7){\oval(3,2)[rt]}
\put(27.5,7){\oval(3,2)[br]}
\put(27.5,7){\oval(3,2)[t]}
\put(25,4.5){\oval(2,3)[b]}
\put(25,4.5){\oval(2,3)[br]}
\put(25,4.5){\oval(2,3)[bl]}
\put(23,4){\oval(2,4)[tr]}
\put(27,4){\oval(2,4)[tl]}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX warns

```
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 10.
```

By default picture mode works by setting characters next to each other so can not make very small shapes that are smaller than the characters.

If you add

```
\usepackage{pict2e}
```

then the definitions are changed to use PDF drawing primitives so these restrictions are lifted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides loading `pict2e`, you can add a couple of small segments to fill in the gaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}
A
\begin{picture}(9,5)
\put(2,4){\oval(3,2)[lt]}
\put(2,4){\oval(3,2)[bl]}
\put(2,4){\oval(3,2)[tr]}
\put(4.5,4){\oval(2,2)[b]}
\put(7,4){\oval(3,2)[rt]}
\put(7,4){\oval(3,2)[br]}
\put(7,4){\oval(3,2)[t]}
\put(4.5,1.5){\oval(2,3)[b]}
\put(4.5,1.5){\oval(2,3)[br]}
\put(4.5,1.5){\oval(2,3)[bl]}
\put(2.5,1){\oval(2,4)[tr]}
\put(6.5,1){\oval(2,4)[tl]}
\put(2,3){\line(1,0){0.5}}  % <---
\put(7,3){\line(-1,0){0.5}} % <---
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

I reduced the size.

[image]